# Is it possible to run two windows sessions from the same computer at the same time?

Tags: windows, session, multiple-users

A friend asked me if it is possible to have two screen/keyboards/mouse connected to one computer, and allowing two users to use the computer as if they where using two different computers (one sessions for each input/output)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In two words : you can't.

This artificial limitation by Microsoft is designed to force you to update to a Server version of the operating system.

However, see this:
[Enable Concurrent Sessions on Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP (Termsrv.dll)](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/windows-guides/1879-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-windows-vista-windows-xp-termsrv-dll.html)

So long as you understand that actually executing these instructions is a violation of the Windows EULA.

Comment: You're talking about multiple remote desktop sessions. The op is asking about multiple physical connections.

Comment: @MarkHenderson: You misunderstood the question. He has 2 physical connections and is asking about using each in a separate session, meaning multi-terminal and not remote desktop (although my answer also pertains to remote desktop).

Comment: The answer is correct even for physical connection: the Windows EULA  does not allow for more than one user at the same time

Comment: Actually there are various products that can do what the op asked. Softxpand (surprisingly good at handling games), Betwin, etc.

Comment: @Fidel:These products emulate desktops, but do not open real Windows sessions because that is impossible without patching Windows. In any case, the products you listed only apply to XP, so are not today of much use.

Comment: Hi Harry, softxpand works on windows 7 just fine. I've been using it for a couple of years. The OP is asking if 2 users can use the computer as if they were using two different computers. Which you can with softxpand. Agree that the two terminals are not separate instances of windows, but the users can do their own thing just fine. Cheers

Comment: @Fidel: It's ok as long as it's understood that some products will malfunction if evoked twice within the same session, which will happen here.

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. Well there seems to be 2 hurdles, the bigger of the two would be multiple instances of Windows. To overcome that challenge you could use Virtual Machines. Use a single host and create 2 virtual machines and just drag each VM on a screen.

To overcome your problem with input devices I found an article on a tool someone found who was trying to do something similar. It *looks* like it handles multiple input devices. You would have to install it on the two VM's and hopefully be able to isolate one set of devices so that each VM has it's dedicated keyboard and mouse.

Here's the link to that article:

[How To Use Multiple Keyboards and Mice On One Computer](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/teamplayer-use-multiple-keyboard-and-mice-on-one-system/)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with Windows [Multi-Point Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/howitworks.aspx). It is not for retail sale, and is only available to educational departments.

For a demo, see [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT2zE5tMglM).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you are using virtualization. See http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can, checkout softxpand duo.
Virtualization kills gpu performance (applies to older cards like ati 5770 but not nvidia gt 640).

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, but with some limitations. also you would want two GPUs

The principle is called "multi-seat" and the only software still supported by the developers, is a Russian-made ASTER by ibik