# Windows 7 - two windows active at the same time

Tags: windows-7, terminal-services, terminal-server

i want to use one PC to play a game and surf the web at the same time. I did some searching and found that it could be done via Windows Terminal Server, but I have no idea how to set it up and how to make it work. Just to clarify, I want to play a game with my wired controller on a HDMI connected TV while someone else uses the computer to do something else (Word, surf the web, etc.)

Does anyone know a good solution for this or can walk me through how to do it using Windows Terminal Server?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with a single instance of Windows. You'd need to look into virtualization to have two instances of Windows running on a single set of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Well on a client base environment I think you cannot. Windows terminal server is mostly to allow RDP connections though. But even when you login to the client it will disconnect/log off current user's session though.

This artificial limitation by Microsoft is designed to force you to update to a Server version of the operating system.

However, see this:

- [**Enable Concurrent Sessions on Windows 7, Windows Vista and Windows XP
  (Termsrv.dll)**](http://digiex.net/guides-reviews/guides-tutorials/windows-guides/1879-enable-concurrent-sessions-windows-7-windows-vista-windows-xp-termsrv-dll.html)

So long as you understand that actually executing these instructions is a violation of the Windows EULA

Source: [**Link**](https://superuser.com/a/214094/241326)

**Optional Solution:** However, I do not know whether this will help  but you may implement a VM (virtual machine) environment to achieve such a requirement.

**Helpful Links:**

- [How can I have multiple active Windows sessions simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/43776/how-can-i-have-multiple-active-windows-sessions-simultaneously)
- [Enable Multiple User Access/Concurrent User Sessions For Remote Desktop on Windows 7](http://www.blogsdna.com/2336/enable-multiple-user-accessconcurrent-user-sessions-for-remote-desktop-on-windows-7.htm)