# Setup for Restaurant/Store

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to setup a Restaurant/Store solution with the minimum $.

Requirements:

- 4 customer service points (point of sales, each with ticket printers, cash registers, display keyboard and a mouse)
- 1 admin computer in the back office (to check the inventory, invoces, etc).

Since space is limited in the point of sales and not in the back office, I was thinking to offer:

- 1 Top notch computer, best processor to store the POS system and database
- 4 cheap basic computers for each point of sale.

All connected by LAN to access the POS Database.

**QUESTION:**

**Is there a solution to create several Windows sessions from one computer?**

That way I can save space on the sales points and money (instead of buying 4 cheap CPUs I will buy USB and VGA extenders for mouse keyboard and display and wire them 30ft away to the main back office super computer PLUS I will only pay one license for the software)

The POS system runs on Windows 7 (not sure if in WinXP).

Or maybe, I can buy the cheap computers with Intel Celeron J1900 to run a linux based system with Mono tu run the program (to save on Windows licenses and make them run faster)

Answer (score 0):

The word I was looking for was "Multiseat".

Wikipedia explains it very easy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration

**In linux I would probably try with Mobo**

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatX

**In Windows I found this**

[Is it possible to run two windows sessions from the same computer at the same time?](https://superuser.com/questions/214074/is-it-possible-to-run-two-windows-sessions-from-the-same-computer-at-the-same-ti)

Programs like Betwin may be an option.