# Is it possible to run two windows sessions from the same computer at the same time? (linux)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, multiple-users

Is possible to have two screen/keyboards/mouse connected to one computer, and allowing two users to use the computer as if they where using two different computers (one sessions for each input/output)

[Is it possible to run two windows sessions from the same computer at the same time? (Windows)](https://superuser.com/questions/214074/is-it-possible-to-run-two-windows-sessions-from-the-same-computer-at-the-same-ti)

Comment: Do you really mean to only ask if it's possible and not *how* to do so?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure is, called "multihead" or "multiseat".  Old LG article/howto - https://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html