# Multiple concurrent users on a same physical machine

Tags: windows, home-server, user

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I share a single computer among different users?](https://superuser.com/questions/192709/how-do-i-share-a-single-computer-among-different-users)

At home, I have 1 PC with 2 screens, 2 mice and 2 keyboards. What is the best way to enable concurrent (simultaneous) users on this PC, in a Windows environement if possible?

Can Windows Server 2008 do that? 
Would I have to log in through RDC or can I log in 2 users directly?

Are there any other viable alternatives, like running unix with 2 virtual machines? I'd like to have pro and cons for each solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen solutions based on MultiEx software, providing 2 workplaces on 1 PC, but it looks like this software is no longer exists. I think [ASTER](http://international.ibik-soft.com/) is something similar

Answer (score 1):

I looked into this a few years ago. For me, I wanted the PC in the closet and then run DVI extender cables around the house. The cost of cabling was too high at the time so I passed on the idea. Here are a few links to point you in the right direction. A Linux and a Windows solution.

[Six-user Linux System](http://linuxgazette.net/124/smith.html)

[Multiple Workstation Windows System](http://www.miniframe.com/)